# Getting v-cards to be responsive

Tags: vuetify.js

I am trying to get my v-cards to be responsive, but I am currently not sure of the best approach of doing it. I want it to wrap on mobile devices (which is does right now), but then I want it to resize on tablet and Desktop devices, which it does, but the content escapes from the v-card container. Does anyone know of a way to resize the content within the v-card as I am resizing the v-card itself?

My code looks like this so far:

```
 <v-container fluid p0>
   <v-layout wrap row justify-center align-content-center>
    <v-flex xs12 sm12 md4 justify-center align-content-center>
      <v-card height="500px" width="550px"  raised hover>
        <v-card-media src="somes" height="300px" contain>
        </v-card-media>
        <v-card-title primary-title>
          <div>
            <h3 class="headline mb-0">Testing</h3>
            <div flex> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a leo ante. Vivamus ac lacinia diam. Aenean sed magna ligula. Vivamus ultrices euismod sapien, non egestas erat semper quis. Curabitur lorem erat, finibus at fringilla ut, egestas id sapien. Suspendisse dignissim felis vitae urna ultrices varius. Integer vulputate augue scelerisque.</div>
          </div>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn flat color="primary">Testing</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>

     <v-flex xs12 sm12 md4 justify-center align-content-center>
          <v-card height="500px" width="550px" raised hover>
        <v-card-media src="some" height="300px">
        </v-card-media>
        <v-card-title primary-title>
          <div>
            <h3 class="headline mb-0">Testing</h3>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a leo ante. Vivamus ac lacinia diam. Aenean sed magna ligula. Vivamus ultrices euismod sapien, non egestas erat semper quis. Curabitur lorem erat, finibus at fringilla ut, egestas id sapien. Suspendisse dignissim felis vitae urna ultrices varius. Integer vulputate augue scelerisque.</div>
          </div>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn flat color="primary">View</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>

     </v-flex>


      <v-flex xs12 sm12 md4 justify-center align-content-center>
          <v-card height="500px" width="550px" raised hover>
        <v-card-media src="/static/doc-images/cards/desert.jpg" height="300px">
        </v-card-media>
        <v-card-title primary-title>
          <div>
            <h3 class="headline mb-0">Testing</h3>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a leo ante. Vivamus ac lacinia diam. Aenean sed magna ligula. Vivamus ultrices euismod sapien, non egestas erat semper quis. Curabitur lorem erat, finibus at fringilla ut, egestas id sapien. Suspendisse dignissim felis vitae urna ultrices varius. Integer vulputate augue scelerisque.</div>
          </div>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn flat color="primary">Testing</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat color="primary">View</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>

     </v-flex>
     </v-layout>
     </v-container>
```

My [codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRxeKa)

Answer (score 0):

The card media fixed height is causing the content to move down and out of the card because the card also has a fixed height

```
<div id="app">
<v-container fluid p0>
   <v-layout wrap row>
    <v-flex xs12 sm12 md4>
      <v-card height="80vh" min-width="30vw" elevation-3 hover>
        <v-card-media src="somes" height="30%" contain>
        </v-card-media>
        <v-card-title primary-title class="headline">Testing
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a leo ante. Vivamus ac lacinia diam. Aenean sed magna ligula. Vivamus ultrices euismod sapien, non egestas erat semper quis. Curabitur lorem erat, finibus at fringilla ut, egestas id sapien. Suspendisse dignissim felis vitae urna ultrices varius. Integer vulputate augue scelerisque.
  </v-card-text >
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn flat color="primary">Testing</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex xs12 sm12 md4>
      <v-card height="80vh" min-width="30vw" elevation-3 hover>
        <v-card-media src="somes" height="30%" contain>
        </v-card-media>
        <v-card-title primary-title class="headline">Testing
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a leo ante. Vivamus ac lacinia diam. Aenean sed magna ligula. Vivamus ultrices euismod sapien, non egestas erat semper quis. Curabitur lorem erat, finibus at fringilla ut, egestas id sapien. Suspendisse dignissim felis vitae urna ultrices varius. Integer vulputate augue scelerisque.
  </v-card-text >
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn flat color="primary">Testing</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex xs12 sm12 md4>
      <v-card height="80vh" min-width="30vw" elevation-3 hover>
        <v-card-media src="somes" height="30%" contain>
        </v-card-media>
        <v-card-title primary-title class="headline">Testing
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a leo ante. Vivamus ac lacinia diam. Aenean sed magna ligula. Vivamus ultrices euismod sapien, non egestas erat semper quis. Curabitur lorem erat, finibus at fringilla ut, egestas id sapien. Suspendisse dignissim felis vitae urna ultrices varius. Integer vulputate augue scelerisque.
  </v-card-text >
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn flat color="primary">Testing</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
</div>
```

Its not an exact solution but this might help to figure out what you want -

[demo codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrRYzJ)